# how do I know if the specific list is a document library?

Tags: list, document-library, soap, wss

when I'm getting all the lists with my Client program from a specific SharePoint server, I'm getting quite a lot of them, but I'd like to present to the user only the Document Libraries. How can I do this? I saw that  a Library can be named anything, not only "Shared Documents", so there must be another possibility? 
I'm currently using WSS/SOAP and talking to the _vti_bin/lists.asmx service with GetListsCollection method, but any clue will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Part of the response for each list is the attribute BaseType which is a string representation of the numeric value from the enumeration [SPBaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasetype.aspx) for each list.

`BaseType="1"` for DocumentLibrary

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon this question but I was looking for Server Object model code. Below code helped me and maybe will help someone else too.

```
                if (objList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
                {
                    //Call function
                }
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way to find List Template type is

```
objList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary
```

Comment: Please check other answers before adding your own.